# Resque Runtime Error at /workers: wrong number of arguments for 'exists' command

Tags: ruby, rubygems, redis, resque, god

I'm having a runtime errror when i'm looking at the "workers" tab on resque-web (localhost). Everything else works.

*Edit: when this error occurs, i also have some (3 or 4) unknown workers 'not working'. I think they are responsible for the error but i don't understand how they got here. It only happens when i start the workers from God*

Can you help me on this ? Did i do something wrong ?

Config:
Resque 1.8.5 as a gem in a rails 2.3.8 app on Snow Leopard
redis 1.0.7 / rack 1.1 / sinatra 1.0 / vegas 0.1.7

- file:  client.rb
- location: format_error_reply
- line: 558

BACKTRACE:

```
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/redis-1.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb in format_error_reply
*
   551. when DOLLAR then format_bulk_reply(line)
   552. when ASTERISK then format_multi_bulk_reply(line)
   553. else raise ProtocolError.new(reply_type)
   554. end
   555. end
   556.
   557. def format_error_reply(line)
   558. raise "-" + line.strip
   559. end
   560.
   561. def format_status_reply(line)
   562. line.strip
   563. end
   564.
   565. def format_integer_reply(line)
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/redis-1.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb in format_reply
*
   541.
   542. def reconnect
   543. disconnect && connect_to_server
   544. end
   545.
   546. def format_reply(reply_type, line)
   547. case reply_type
   548. when MINUS then format_error_reply(line)
   549. when PLUS then format_status_reply(line)
   550. when COLON then format_integer_reply(line)
   551. when DOLLAR then format_bulk_reply(line)
   552. when ASTERISK then format_multi_bulk_reply(line)
   553. else raise ProtocolError.new(reply_type)
   554. end
   555. end
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/redis-1.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb in read_reply
*
   478. disconnect
   479.
   480. raise Errno::EAGAIN, "Timeout reading from the socket"
   481. end
   482.
   483. raise Errno::ECONNRESET, "Connection lost" unless reply_type
   484.
   485. format_reply(reply_type, @sock.gets)
   486. end
   487.
   488.
   489. if "".respond_to?(:bytesize)
   490. def get_size(string)
   491. string.bytesize
   492. end
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/redis-1.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb in process_command
*
   448. return pipeline ? results : results[0]
   449. end
   450.
   451. def process_command(command, argvv)
   452. @sock.write(command)
   453. argvv.map do |argv|
   454. processor = REPLY_PROCESSOR[argv[0].to_s]
   455. processor ? processor.call(read_reply) : read_reply
   456. end
   457. end
   458.
   459. def maybe_lock(&block)
   460. if @thread_safe
   461. @mutex.synchronize(&block)
   462. else
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/redis-1.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb in map
*
   446. end
   447.
   448. return pipeline ? results : results[0]
   449. end
   450.
   451. def process_command(command, argvv)
   452. @sock.write(command)
   453. argvv.map do |argv|
   454. processor = REPLY_PROCESSOR[argv[0].to_s]
   455. processor ? processor.call(read_reply) : read_reply
   456. end
   457. end
   458.
   459. def maybe_lock(&block)
   460. if @thread_safe
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/redis-1.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb in process_command
*
   446. end
   447.
   448. return pipeline ? results : results[0]
   449. end
   450.
   451. def process_command(command, argvv)
   452. @sock.write(command)
   453. argvv.map do |argv|
   454. processor = REPLY_PROCESSOR[argv[0].to_s]
   455. processor ? processor.call(read_reply) : read_reply
   456. end
   457. end
   458.
   459. def maybe_lock(&block)
   460. if @thread_safe
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/redis-1.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb in raw_call_command
*
   435. @sock.write(command)
   436. return true
   437. end
   438. # The normal command execution is reading and processing the reply.
   439. results = maybe_lock do
   440. begin
   441. set_socket_timeout!(0) if requires_timeout_reset?(argvv[0][0].to_s)
   442. process_command(command, argvv)
   443. ensure
   444. set_socket_timeout!(@timeout) if requires_timeout_reset?(argvv[0][0].to_s)
   445. end
   446. end
   447.
   448. return pipeline ? results : results[0]
   449. end
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/redis-1.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb in synchronize
*
   454. processor = REPLY_PROCESSOR[argv[0].to_s]
   455. processor ? processor.call(read_reply) : read_reply
   456. end
   457. end
   458.
   459. def maybe_lock(&block)
   460. if @thread_safe
   461. @mutex.synchronize(&block)
   462. else
   463. block.call
   464. end
   465. end
   466.
   467. def read_reply
   468.
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/redis-1.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb in maybe_lock
*
   454. processor = REPLY_PROCESSOR[argv[0].to_s]
   455. processor ? processor.call(read_reply) : read_reply
   456. end
   457. end
   458.
   459. def maybe_lock(&block)
   460. if @thread_safe
   461. @mutex.synchronize(&block)
   462. else
   463. block.call
   464. end
   465. end
   466.
   467. def read_reply
   468.
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/redis-1.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb in raw_call_command
*
   432. end
   433. # When in Pub/Sub mode we don't read replies synchronously.
   434. if @pubsub
   435. @sock.write(command)
   436. return true
   437. end
   438. # The normal command execution is reading and processing the reply.
   439. results = maybe_lock do
   440. begin
   441. set_socket_timeout!(0) if requires_timeout_reset?(argvv[0][0].to_s)
   442. process_command(command, argvv)
   443. ensure
   444. set_socket_timeout!(@timeout) if requires_timeout_reset?(argvv[0][0].to_s)
   445. end
   446. end
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/redis-1.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb in call_command
*
   336. # try to reconnect just one time, otherwise let the error araise.
   337. def call_command(argv)
   338. log(argv.inspect, :debug)
   339.
   340. connect_to_server unless connected?
   341.
   342. begin
   343. raw_call_command(argv.dup)
   344. rescue Errno::ECONNRESET, Errno::EPIPE, Errno::ECONNABORTED
   345. if reconnect
   346. raw_call_command(argv.dup)
   347. else
   348. raise Errno::ECONNRESET
   349. end
   350. end
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/redis-1.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb in method_missing
*
   385. connect_to(@host, @port)
   386. call_command([:auth, @password]) if @password
   387. call_command([:select, @db]) if @db != 0
   388. @sock
   389. end
   390.
   391. def method_missing(*argv)
   392. call_command(argv)
   393. end
   394.
   395. def raw_call_command(argvp)
   396. if argvp[0].is_a?(Array)
   397. argvv = argvp
   398. pipeline = true
   399. else
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/redis-namespace-0.4.4/lib/redis/namespace.rb in send
*
   159. args = add_namespace(args)
   160. args.push(last) if last
   161. when :alternate
   162. args = [ add_namespace(Hash[*args]) ]
   163. end
   164.
   165. # Dispatch the command to Redis and store the result.
   166. result = @redis.send(command, *args, &block)
   167.
   168. # Remove the namespace from results that are keys.
   169. result = rem_namespace(result) if after == :all
   170.
   171. result
   172. end
   173.
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/redis-namespace-0.4.4/lib/redis/namespace.rb in method_missing
*
   159. args = add_namespace(args)
   160. args.push(last) if last
   161. when :alternate
   162. args = [ add_namespace(Hash[*args]) ]
   163. end
   164.
   165. # Dispatch the command to Redis and store the result.
   166. result = @redis.send(command, *args, &block)
   167.
   168. # Remove the namespace from results that are keys.
   169. result = rem_namespace(result) if after == :all
   170.
   171. result
   172. end
   173.
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/resque-1.8.5/lib/resque/worker.rb in state
*
   416. def idle?
   417. state == :idle
   418. end
   419.
   420. # Returns a symbol representing the current worker state,
   421. # which can be either :working or :idle
   422. def state
   423. redis.exists("worker:#{self}") ? :working : :idle
   424. end
   425.
   426. # Is this worker the same as another worker?
   427. def ==(other)
   428. to_s == other.to_s
   429. end
   430.
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/resque-1.8.5/lib/resque/server/views/workers.erb in __tilt_a2112543c5200dbe0635da5124b47311
*
    46. <tr>
    47. <th>&nbsp;</th>
    48. <th>Where</th>
    49. <th>Queues</th>
    50. <th>Processing</th>
    51. </tr>
    52. <% for worker in (workers = resque.workers.sort_by { |w| w.to_s }) %>
    53. <tr class="<%=state = worker.state%>">
    54. <td class='icon'><img src="<%=u state %>.png" alt="<%= state %>" title="<%= state %>"></td>
    55.
    56. <% host, pid, queues = worker.to_s.split(':') %>
    57. <td class='where'><a href="<%=u "workers/#{worker}"%>"><%= host %>:<%= pid %></a></td>
    58. <td class='queues'><%= queues.split(',').map { |q| '<a class="queue-tag" href="' + u("/queues/#{q}") + '">' + q + '</a>'}.join('') %></td>
    59.
    60. <td class='process'>
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/resque-1.8.5/lib/resque/server/views/workers.erb in each
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/resque-1.8.5/lib/resque/server/views/workers.erb in __tilt_a2112543c5200dbe0635da5124b47311
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/tilt.rb in send
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/tilt.rb in evaluate
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/tilt.rb in render
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb in render
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb in erb
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/resque-1.8.5/lib/resque/server.rb in show
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/resque-1.8.5/lib/resque/server.rb in GET /workers
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb in call
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb in route
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb in instance_eval
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb in route_eval
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb in route!
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb in catch
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb in route!
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb in each
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb in route!
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb in dispatch!
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb in call!
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb in instance_eval
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb in invoke
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb in catch
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb in invoke
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb in call!
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb in call
* /Volumes/Donnees/Users/**/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/showexceptions.rb in call
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb in call
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb in synchronize
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb in call
* /Volumes/Donnees/Users/**/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/content_length.rb in call
* /Volumes/Donnees/Users/**/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/chunked.rb in call
* /Volumes/Donnees/Users/**/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb in process
* /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb in process_client
* /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb in each
* /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb in process_client
* /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb in run
* /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb in initialize
* /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb in new
* /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb in run
* /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb in initialize
* /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb in new
* /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb in run
* /Volumes/Donnees/Users/**/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb in run
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vegas-0.1.7/lib/vegas/runner.rb in run!
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vegas-0.1.7/lib/vegas/runner.rb in start
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/resque-1.8.5/bin/resque-web in new
* /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/resque-1.8.5/bin/resque-web in nil
* /usr/bin/resque-web in load
```

Comment: It raises the same error when i do 'resque list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem :

in god config file, i had (with spaces after the comma in QUEUE):

```
num_workers.times do |num|
  God.watch do |w|
    w.name = "resque-#{num}"
    w.group = 'resque'
    w.interval = 30.seconds
    w.env = {"QUEUE"=>"critical, high, low", "RAILS_ENV"=>rails_env}
```

instead of (without spaces after comma):

```
num_workers.times do |num|
  God.watch do |w|
    w.name = "resque-#{num}"
    w.group = 'resque'
    w.interval = 30.seconds
    w.env = {"QUEUE"=>"critical,high,low", "RAILS_ENV"=>rails_env}
```

Now it works !!